# Transfer contacts from a phone with non-functioning screen

Tags: contacts

I have a HTC 510 Desire.An I try to tranfer my contacts but the touch screen does not work. How can I get my contacts?

Comment: Have you tried searching for other appropriate answers here? Here is a [query](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=screen+broken+transfer+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) with about a dozen questions of a similar nature (transferring data from a broken-screen device) with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**PC companion software**

The only way to do it is if you use HTC's pc companion software to sync the device with the pc and then use the software to the pc and then to your new device.

The software can be downloaded from HTC's site [here](http://www.htc.com/uk/software/htc-sync-manager/)